# showing DIV on Hover - overflow auto

Tags: css, html, z-index

I want to show a div by hovering over its parent.
The code is quite big so I'll try to explain.
On the site there is a scrollable div (overflow:auto) which shows a table.
-> it shows 10 lines of the table and the rest (nearly 30) must be scrolled.

In every tr of my table there is a div(hover_over) that has a child-div (show_by_hower)
By hovering over the div (hover_over) the child-div (show_by_hower) should be displayed.
That works so far but the child-div (show_by_hower) is always under the scrolling div.
If I remove the `overflow:auto;` from the scrollable div it all works fine but I need the overflow auto.

```
#hover_over 
{
     position:relative;
     width:20px;height:20px;
}

#hover_over:hover div
{
     position:absolute;
     display:block;
     z-index:999;
     width:310px;
     height:125px;
}

#hover_over div { display:none; }
```

There is no other positioning in the code.

Comment: Show some HTML, or, better yet, a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: ok i created a fiddle that shows my prob. http://jsfiddle.net/uy2xe/1/  The green box should be on top of all

Comment: I think you'll have to use JavaScript to accomplish that...

Comment: Here's [my fork of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/E8Tcy/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/8xByv/) with one possible solution.  I'm using jQuery's `.hover()` method to animate an element outside of the table and fill it with the content contained inside the table. This way, your pop-up element is not restricted to the bounds of the table.

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    $(".hover_over").hover( function() {
        hovDiv = $(this);
        showDiv = $(".show_hover");
        showDiv.html(hovDiv.children("div").html());
        showDiv.css("top", hovDiv.offset().top)
        showDiv.css("left", hovDiv.offset().left + hovDiv.width()).show();
    }, function() {
        $(".show_hover").hide();
    });
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="theTable">
    <div class="hover_over">1
        <div>I'm hidden! 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="hover_over">2
        <div>I'm hidden! 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="hover_over">3
        <div>I'm hidden! 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="hover_over">4
        <div>I'm hidden! 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="hover_over">5
        <div>I'm hidden! 5</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="show_hover"></div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.show_hover {
   display:none;
   position:absolute;
   background-color:black;
   width:100px;
   height:20px;
   font-size:14px;
   color:white;
}

.hover_over div { display:none; }
```

### Update

Because you asked, I decided to make this work with plain javascript. It is not as easy to read, but the same idea applies: move the popup div outside the table and dynamically add the desired content and positioning with `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` event handlers.

[Here is the new jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/E8Tcy/11/).

And here is the relevant code:

**Javascript**

```
(function() {
    function hoverIn() {
        var hovDiv = this;
        var showDiv = document.getElementById("show_hover");
        showDiv.innerHTML = hovDiv.children[0].innerHTML;
        showDiv.className = "see";
        var newTop = hovDiv.offsetTop + hovDiv.offsetParent.offsetTop +  hovDiv.offsetParent.offsetParent.offsetTop;
        showDiv.style.top = "" + newTop + "px";
        var newLeft = hovDiv.offsetLeft + hovDiv.offsetParent.offsetLeft +    hovDiv.offsetParent.offsetParent.offsetLeft + hovDiv.clientWidth;
        showDiv.style.left = "" + newLeft + "px";
    };

    function hoverOut() {
        document.getElementById("show_hover").className = "";
    };

    var hoverDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("hoverdiv");
    for(var i = 0; i < hoverDivs.length; i++)
    {
      hoverDivs[i].onmouseover = hoverIn;
      hoverDivs[i].onmouseout = hoverOut;
    }

})();
```

**CSS**

```
#show_hover
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

#show_hover.see {
    display:block;   
    background-color:green;
    width:400px;
    height:80px;
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
}
```

### Update 2

This answer is getting insanely long. [Here's the new jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/E8Tcy/12/). This update allows you to hover over the shown div to interact with the objects inside. I made use of the basic idea behind the [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) jQuery plugin, which is to place the `onmouseout` handler behind a `setTimeout` call that allows you half a second to move your mouse into the popup before it disappears. It's a bit fidgety, so you might play with the wait time until it does what you want.

Also, see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397356/check-if-mouse-is-within-elements-bounds) if you want to just check to see where the mouse is at any given moment and trigger the show/hide behavior off that.

That said, here's the important part of the update:

```
    var mouseInShowHover = false;
    var showDiv = document.getElementById("show_hover");

    showDiv.onmouseover = function() { mouseInShowHover = true; }

    showDiv.onmouseout = function() {
        mouseInShowHover = false;
        showDiv.className = "";
    }

    function hoverOut() {
        setTimeout( function() {
            if( !mouseInShowHover )
               showDiv.className = "";
        }, 500);
    };
```

Comment: thanks for the solution - but i dont use jquery so far. is there a solution without jquery ?

Comment: With this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/E8Tcy/11/ the green box gets more offset the further down you go. I don't see that in your jQuery version.

Comment: @LittleBigBot I'm not seeing it in Chrome. Which browser do you run?

Comment: @AustinMullins Chrome v25 on a Mac.

Comment: LOL. I'll try to remember to look at it at home then. We only have Windows machines at TSTC. I really hate using plain js anyway.

Comment: thanks so far for your great help. sometimes i thought about using jquery but i dont know how the performance should change by using jquery. should i include the jquery framework only for using the hover function ?

Comment: No. You should include it if you want to use it. I love it, but it's your call.

Comment: ok austin thanks. just one question. is it possible to change the script that the hover div (green box) will stay so the user can klick a link on the hover div ? the green box should close by leaving the green box.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. It worked that way automatically before because the hover pop-up was inside the row element. Now that it's outside it will be a little trickier. I'm on it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your JSFiddle example worked fine for me, so I'm assuming you're using IE8 or something that has very strict z-index rules.

Try adding this:

```
#divscroll tr:hover {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/uy2xe/3/).

Comment: I'm in Chrome v25 and `overflow:auto` is taking over for me. The OP wants the popup to display outside the containing div.

Comment: @AustinMullins Oh! I misunderstood, I'll see if I can figure that out, thanks.